# Update 11.04 to 12.04 with LiveCD

Tags: 11.04, installation, upgrade, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade straight from a very old release to the latest one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/how-do-i-upgrade-straight-from-a-very-old-release-to-the-latest-one)

I'm trying to update my current Ubuntu 11.04 install to 12.04 while keeping the files, settings and installed applications but **without** having to go through updating to Ubuntu 11.10 as an intermediate step, that is, **without using Ubuntu Update Manager**.

I've read on the Internet that the LiveCD (and possibly LiveUSB too) installer offers an option to upgrade a version older than 11.10 in the installer. However, it is not available to me.

More specifically, I'm looking for the second option in this screenshot:
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_1QSDkzYY2vc/TWzh8Z786xI/AAAAAAAADNw/8lXqgCMgicY/s2000/ubuntu11.04-installer.png

...but with the version numbers changed to 12.04 (I swear I've seen a screenshot of the 12.04 Beta version installer with that option, but can't find it now). Has it been removed from the 12.04 LTS installer?

Or should I be using the alternate CD?

It's very important to me not to have to go through two Ubuntu versions as my internet connection is slow and downloading 11.10 first would be a waste of bandwidth as well as time (both for downloading and installation).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition between 11.04 to 11.10 was quite dramatic since it involved moving from GTK+2/gnome libraries to GTK+3/gnome libraries.  This is the support route that was well tested.

Similarly well tested is the similar 10.04LTS to 12.04 LTS upgrade.

Moving from 11.04 to 12.04 in one step is not supported and I urge you not to go down this route since you are more likely to break your desktop & installation.

Since you have downloaded 12.04 - I would go for a fresh install.

If you have any files & folders from your 11.04 install, back these up - you can reinstall these later.

Comment: I forgot that the 11.10 upgrade introduced Gnome 3 libraries and that makes upgrading harder. The reason why I won't do a fresh install is that although all my files are in Ubuntu One and most apps can be installed again quite easily, I have some development setups with binaries in /usr/bin, custom packages (not in repos) and other customized things. But juding by your question I'll just upgrade in two steps like it's meant to be. Thanks again.