# Upgrade Ubuntu 11.04 to 12.04 offline?

Tags: 12.04, 11.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update 11.04 to 12.04 with LiveCD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125600/update-11-04-to-12-04-with-livecd)

Apologize if question already exists,

I have 5 drives, in 'c' drive i have installed windows xp pro and in 'h' drive i have installed ubuntu 11.04 with duel boot between ubuntu 11.04 and windows xp pro,

Now i want to Upgrade ubuntu 11.04 to 12.04 **offline** i have downloaded ubuntu 12.04 **iso** image,

is there is any way to upgrade without internet and without disturbing my others **Drivers**?

Hope i am in right place and i hope i get help .

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04 directly, you'll need to upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 and then from 11.10 to 12.04.

So the answer to your question is NO - if all you have is 12.04 ISO image and no internet access, the only way to get 12.04 is to install it either separately or on top of 11.04.

(additionally, I'm not sure it's even possible to upgrade using ISO at all - most of the software you install after installing Ubuntu is not included on the cdrom. A typical download when upgrading from version to version is 1.5-2Gb)

Answer (score 0):

As noted by **@Sergey**, you can't really update directly from 11.04 to 12.04 ..

This needs to be done in two steps:  11.04 to 11.10, then 11.10 to 12.04

Once you also have media (either USB or CD/DVD) with the .ISO files for both **11.10** and **12.04**, then you **can** do this offline.

Comment: with the caveat that you can't just go from 11.10 to 12.04 directly, first you must upgrade all packages. (Or, at least, you're supposed to.)